# Array transformation in D3

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

What is best way to transform array from this

```js
[{
  "state": "vic",
  "age_group_1": 10,
  "age_group_2": 20,
  "age_group_3": 30,
  "age_group_4": 40,
  "age_group_5": 50,
}, {
  "state": "nsw",
  "age_group_1": 60,
  "age_group_2": 70,
  "age_group_3": 80,
  "age_group_4": 90,
  "age_group_5": 100,
}, {
  "state": "tas",
  "age_group_1": 11,
  "age_group_2": 21,
  "age_group_3": 31,
  "age_group_4": 41,
  "age_group_5": 51,
}, {
  "state": "qld",
  "age_group_1": 61,
  "age_group_2": 71,
  "age_group_3": 81,
  "age_group_4": 91,
  "age_group_5": 101,
}]
```

to this

```js
[{
  "age_group": "age_group_1",
  "states": [{
    "name": "vic",
    "value": 10
  }, {
    "name": "nsw",
    "value": 60
  }, {
    "name": "tas",
    "value": 11
  }, {
    "name": "qld",
    "value": 61
  }]
}, {
  "age_group": "age_group_2",
  "states": [{
    "name": "vic",
    "value": 20
  }, {
    "name": "nsw",
    "value": 70
  }, {
    "name": "tas",
    "value": 21
  }, {
    "name": "qld",
    "value": 71
  }]
}, {
  "age_group": "age_group_3",
  "states": [{
    "name": "vic",
    "value": 30
  }, {
    "name": "nsw",
    "value": 80
  }, {
    "name": "tas",
    "value": 31
  }, {
    "name": "qld",
    "value": 81
  }]
}, {
  "age_group": "age_group_5",
  "states": [{
    "name": "vic",
    "value": 40
  }, {
    "name": "nsw",
    "value": 90
  }, {
    "name": "tas",
    "value": 41
  }, {
    "name": "qld",
    "value": 91
  }]
}, {
  "age_group": "age_group_5",
  "states": [{
    "name": "vic",
    "value": 50
  }, {
    "name": "nsw",
    "value": 100
  }, {
    "name": "tas",
    "value": 51
  }, {
    "name": "qld",
    "value": 101
  }]
}]
```

using simple javascript and looping I can do but I want to use *either d3 functions or may be any other library* that deal with data transformation.

Which is best library for data transformation.

Comment: "plain Javascript". Why do you want to use D3 when JS has all the functions to do this *built into the language*?

Comment: Apologies @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans! Misread the question. And I do agree with your point of transforming using pure JS and then feeding it to D3

Comment: @Microchip78, can you share your code through which you were able to transform, and we might be able to improve that

Comment: is the `age_groups` always 5 in each state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage of modern JS instead of trying to make D3 do it - it's pretty simple code:

```
var basedata = the original array from your question;

// I assume your data already has this array of categories somewhere,
// but if it doesn't, let's just declare it here:
var age_groups = [
  "age_group_1",
  "age_group_2",
  "age_group_3",
  "age_group_4",
  "age_group_5"
];

var transformed = age_groups.map(group => {
  return {
    age_group: group,
    states: basedata.map(set => {
      return { state: set.state, value: set[group] }
    })
  };
});
```

And done.

The reason this works is because you want objects keyed on your age groups, so we start by making sure we create a mapping based on those. Then, for each age group, we simply run through the base data and return the state/value pair. Nothing really complex, and ES6/ES2015 does the job for us.

Don't like ES6/ES2015? Good opportunity to get with the times, but also really easily rewritten to older ES5 format: replace each `(...) => { ... }` with `function(...) { return ... }` and done.

Comment: Thank you so much Mike ... this works like a charm ... I was not aware of this functions exists in JS as mostly I use js for dom manipulation purpose only so far ... since I started exploring d3 I started dealing with data in client side ...

Answer (score 3):

You could use a temporary object for the reference to the result array.

```js
var data = [{ "state": "vic", "age_group_1": 10, "age_group_2": 20, "age_group_3": 30, "age_group_4": 40, "age_group_5": 50, }, { "state": "nsw", "age_group_1": 60, "age_group_2": 70, "age_group_3": 80, "age_group_4": 90, "age_group_5": 100, }, { "state": "tas", "age_group_1": 11, "age_group_2": 21, "age_group_3": 31, "age_group_4": 41, "age_group_5": 51, }, { "state": "qld", "age_group_1": 61, "age_group_2": 71, "age_group_3": 81, "age_group_4": 91, "age_group_5": 101, }],
       result = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
        if (k !== 'state') {
            if (!this[k]) {
                this[k] = { age_group: k, states: [] };
                result.push(this[k]);
            }
            this[k].states.push({ name: a.state, value: a[k] });
        }
    }, this);
}, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```js
var data=[{state:"vic",age_group_1:10,age_group_2:20,age_group_3:30,age_group_4:40,age_group_5:50},{state:"nsw",age_group_1:60,age_group_2:70,age_group_3:80,age_group_4:90,age_group_5:100},{state:"tas",age_group_1:11,age_group_2:21,age_group_3:31,age_group_4:41,age_group_5:51},{state:"qld",age_group_1:61,age_group_2:71,age_group_3:81,age_group_4:91,age_group_5:101}];

var _tmp = {}
var kepReg = /^age_group/;
data.forEach(function(item) {
  for (var k in item) {
    if (kepReg.test(k)) {
      if (!_tmp[k])
        _tmp[k] = {
          state: []
        };
      _tmp[k].state.push({
        name: item["state"],
        value: item[k]
      })
    }
  }
});

var result = Object.keys(_tmp).map(function(k) {
  return {
    age_group: k,
    states: _tmp[k].state
  }
});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + "</pre>")
```

Comment: using the built-in [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function (part of JS for a while now) lets you write this in less than 10 lines, though.

Comment: I'm aware about that and I've used in it my answer. But my answer takes entire json and using values of age-group, create object. So this will work even if any new value is added